# Trim image to smallest square

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have a PNG. I want to trim it down to the smallest possible image while keeping the canvas square.

For example, I have this non-square image with a transparent background:

[image]

If I run `convert input.png -trim +repage output.png`, the image is trimmed on all sides:

[image]

I want a **square** image, where the longest side of the trimmed image is the height and width of the square.  For example:

[image]

I thought about using `-gravity center -extent 512x512` - but I don't always know what the size should be for the extent.

How do I get the longest side of a trimmed image, and resize the canvas based on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using FX expressions to set the page geometry like this...

```
convert input.png -trim -background none \
   -set page "%[fx:max(w,h)]x%[fx:max(w,h)]+%[fx:(max(w,h)-w)/2]+%[fx:(max(w,h)-h)/2]" \
   -coalesce output.png
```

That trims the input and calculates the maximum of the width or height to determine the dimensions of the square. Then it sets the geometry to locate the input image in the center of the square. The "-coalesce" re-composes the input to conform to that canvas size and geometry.

This will work with images that have either landscape or portrait orientation.

To use this as a Windows command, change the continued line backslashes "\" to carets "^". In a Windows BAT script, make the single percent signs "%" into doubles "%%".

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3):

You do not say what version of Imagemagick you are using which can have an effect on the answer.

This is a V7 answer and you can follow the same process on V6 but it may be a bit more long winded.

```
magick "input.png" -trim -background none -gravity center -extent %wx%w "output.png"
```

Comment: I've just upgraded to 7 - and your solution works well. Thanks!